# Cannot pass new selected dropdown value to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC application. Here is a part of my code:

View Model:

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllDepartments { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentId, Model.AllDepartments)
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(StudentViewModel studentViewModel)
    {
```

After the user changes the department selection in the dropdown and submits, for some reason the studentViewModel.DepartmentId contains the old DepartmentId. studentViewModel.Name does contain the new value. What am I missing?

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you have shown. Do you have any javascript which may be interfering? Have you included a hidden input for the same property? Check your browser tools to see what is actually posted.

Comment: Make sure you dont have an attribute with the name DepartmentID in your view

Comment: @Osadellah, I think you mean a `name` (not `id`) attribute :)

Comment: Also make sure the dropdown is inside your form code and not outside

Comment: @Stephen Muecke You were right! There was a field for the same DepartmentId! if you create an answer, I will be able to mark it as such. Thank you and Osadellah, who also gave the same answer, just 4 minutes later :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, you have included another control for property `DepartmentId` before the dropdownlist. The `DefaultModelBinder` reads all form values in order (plus route values, query string values etc). Once a property value has been set, any subsequent values for the same property are ignored.